# Keep history of deleted characters in Notepad

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am monitoring Notepad activities.  I want the character that gets deleted when we press `backspace` or `delete`.

In addition, I don't want to modify the existing clipboard contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best solution, but you can do almost anything like this with a little creativity and [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Here's a sample AHK script I wrote.  It executes custom code whenever a user presses `backspace` or `delete` in a notepad window.  Pressing `Ctrl+Shift+z` will give you a message box with the delete history.  It does make use of the clipboard, but it restores it back to the original value.

This was a 5 minute hack, so I'm sure there are issues with it.  Use at your own risk :)

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance
SendMode Input

_removalHistory =
_backupClipboard =

#IfWinActive, ahk_classNotepad
{
    Backspace::Delete("left")
    Delete::Delete("right")
    ^+z::MsgBox %_removalHistory%
}

Delete(direction) {
    global

    BackupAndClearClipboard()               

    length := GetSelectedLength()
    if length = 0 SelectOneCharacter(direction)

    Copy()   
    _removalHistory = %_removalHistory%%clipboard%
    Send {Delete}

    RestoreClipboard() 
}

GetSelectedLength() {
    local length = 0
    Copy()
    StringLen, length, clipboard    
    return length
}

SelectOneCharacter(direction) {   
    if (direction = "left") {
       Send +{Left}
    }
    else if (direction = "right") {
       Send +{Right}
    }
}

Copy() {
    Send ^c
    ClipWait 0.01
}

BackupAndClearClipboard() {
    global
    _backupClipboard := ClipboardAll      
    clipboard =   
}

RestoreClipboard() {
    global
    clipboard := _backupClipboard
    _backupClipboard =              ;free memory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of where it might be possible to do something like this is to inject a DLL into notepad which would let you automate it but I'm not sure if it could pick up this.
An article about how to do this can be found at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/automatingwindowsapps.aspx

However, I'd think that it might actually be easier to write your own notepad replacement that could do this for you. Possibly you could just download the source for NotePad++ or similar and amend it.